# Angular 2+ textarea placeholder conditioned and with translate

Tags: angular, angular-translate

**conditioned:**

```
<textarea
    class="form-control"
    [placeholder]="(i < 3) ? 'a' : 'b'">
</textarea>
```

a a a b b b b b b b b b

**with translate:**

```
<textarea
    class="form-control"
    placeholder="{{'STEPS.PLACEHOLDER' | translate}} {{title$ | async}}"
</textarea>
```

Title is foo

**but I need conditioned and with translate:**

```
<textarea
    class="form-control"
    ?placeholder?="?????"
</textarea>
```

1st title is foo

2nd title is foo

3th title is foo

next title is foo

next title is foo

next title is foo

next title is foo

next title is foo

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<textarea
    class="form-control"
    [placeholder]="(i < 3) ? ('STEPS.PLACEHOLDER_' + i | translate) + ' ' + (title$ | async) : ('STEPS.PLACEHOLDER_ELSE' | translate) + ' ' + (title$ | async)"
</textarea>
```

Comment: a stupid user has down voted but this is the best answer!!